# kubernetes: Call command in another containers which are in same pod

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any approach that one container can call command in another container? The containers are in the same pod.

I need many command line tools which are shipped as image as well as in packages. But I don’t want to install all of them into one container because of some concerns.

Comment: @nsheff just FYI, [it's best](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641) to disclose that you are [an author](https://github.com/databio/bulker) of this project for transparency's sake. Thanks for the link though, it does seem relevant to the topic.

Comment: @jrh oh, I was just trying to be helpful. I'm not just an author I'm basically THE author. bulker was the way I solved this very question for my use case. I've removed my comment, as I don't want to come across even remotely as spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no, you can't do this in Kubernetes (or in plain Docker).  You should either move the two interconnected things into the same container, or wrap some sort of network service around the thing you're trying to call (and then probably put it in a separate pod with a separate service in front of it).

There *might* be something you could do if you set up a service account, installed a Kubernetes API sidecar container, and used the Kubernetes API to do the equivalent of `kubectl exec`, but I'd consider this a solution of last resort.

Comment: `connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec` takes the name of the pod to execute in, wouldn't that mean you'd have to find the name of your own pod and store it somewhere? I could not find any way to pass a "`this` pod" instead.  Is that why this is considered a solution of last resort?

Answer (score 6):

This is very possible as long as you have k8s v1.17+. You must enable `shareProcessNamespace: true` and then all the container processes are available to other containers in the same pod.

[Here are the docs, have a look.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/)

Comment: While this way we have access to another container's filesystem, I think we can't execute executables from their filesystem. I deployed the sample Pod in the doc and when trying to execute `/proc/8/root/usr/sbin/nginx` inside the `shell` container, it gave me `/bin/sh: /proc/8/root/usr/sbin/nginx: not found` error. (running `/usr/sbin/nginx` inside `nginx` container was fine)

Comment: @AliTou I am inclined to agree, there is something missing here, it feels like you would have to do a `chroot` from container A to container B's filesystem, pretty much. What if a program in container B needed libraries that were only present in container A? I don't understand what use case this answer solves, it seems like it would only be a solution if you wanted to just pipe information into a running process on another container?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without `shareProcessNamespace` by using a shared volume and some named pipes. It manages all the I/O for you and is trivially simple and extremely fast.

For a complete description and code, see [this solution](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2500587) I created. Contains examples.

Answer (score 2):

Containers in pod are isolated from each other except that they share volume and network namespace. So you would not be able to execute command from one container into another. However, you could expose the commands in container through APIs

Answer (score 1):

We are currently running EKS v1.20 and we were able to achieve this using the `shareProcessNamespace: true` that mr haven mention. In our particular case, we needed a debian 10 php container to execute a SAS binary command with arguments. SAS is installed and running in a centos 7 container in the same pod. Using helm, we enabled shareProcessNamespace and in the container's arguments and command fields we built symlinks to that binary using bash -c once the pod came online. We grabbed the pid of the shared container by using `pgrep` and since we know that the centos container's entry point is `tail -f /dev/null` so we just look for that process `$(pgrep tail)` initially.

```
- image: some_php_container
         command: ["bash", "-c"]
         args: [ "SAS_PROC_PID=$(pgrep tail) && \
                  ln -sf /proc/$SAS_PROC_PID/root/usr/local/SAS/SAS_9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/bin/sas_u8 /usr/bin/sas && \
                  ln -sf /proc/$SAS_PROC_PID/root/usr/local/SAS /usr/local/SAS && \
                  . /opt/script_runner.sh" ]
```

Now the php container is able to execute the sas command with arguments and process data files using the SAS software running on the centos container.

One issue we quickly found out is if the resulting SAS container happened to die in the pod, the pid would change and thus the symlinks would be broken on the php container. So we just put in liveness probe to frequently check to see if the path to binary using current pid exist, if the probe fails, it restarts the php container and thus rebuilding the symlinks with the right pid.

```
livenessProbe:
    exec:
      command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - SAS_PROC_PID=$(pgrep tail)
      - test -f /proc/$SAS_PROC_PID/root/usr/local/SAS/SAS_9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/bin/sas_u8
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 1
```

Hopefully above info can help someone else.